# Rectangle at given Tikz-Marks in listing is not drawn, but same rectangle at different marks is

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I have a problem again, with Tikz and Rectangles. The second rectangle is not being drawn, but the first is. Even if I remove everything except the second `fill` (including the canvas transform and scope), it won't be drawn either.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\lstset{
   language=C++,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
   numbers=left,
   captionpos=b
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,tikzmark,calc}
% This is the file main.tex
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Wiedereintrittsfähiges Interface}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
float flicker_float(bool restart, ActiveConfig<Traits> config,
                    float sample) 
{
   // save to 'state'
   %\tikzmark{statb}%static Impl state;%\tikzmark{state}%
   $\ldots$
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
float flicker_float_r(bool restart, ActiveConfig<Traits> config,
                      float sample, %\tikzmark{parb}%Impl *state%\tikzmark{pare}%) 
{
   // save to *state
   $\ldots$
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=-2pt}]
  \fill[opacity=.1] (pic cs:statb) rectangle ($(pic cs:state) + (0,10pt)$ -| {pic cs:state});
  \fill[opacity=.1] (pic cs:parb) rectangle ($(pic cs:parb) + (0,10pt)$ -| {pic cs:pare});
  \draw[->] (pic cs:statb) -| ([xshift=-5pt]pic cs:parb) -- +(5pt,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I use `filldraw` instead of `fill`, I see a tiny fraction of the left border of the second rectangle. This would suggest a clipping problem, but I'm out of guesses as to what causes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a coordinate problem, not a clipping problem. If you try

```
\draw (pic cs:parb) -- ($(pic cs:parb) + (0,10pt)$ -| {pic cs:pare});
```

you'll see that you get a straight vertical line. I.e. the second coordinate ends up directly above the first one. I can't see exactly why it ends up that way, but a couple of simpler approaches could be

```
\fill[opacity=0.1] (pic cs:parb) rectangle ([yshift=10pt]pic cs:pare);
```

or

```
\fill[opacity=0.1] (pic cs:parb) rectangle ($(pic cs:pare) + (0,10pt)$);
```

which both work fine.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\lstset{
   language=C++,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
   numbers=left,
   captionpos=b
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,tikzmark,calc}
% This is the file main.tex
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Wiedereintrittsfähiges Interface}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
float flicker_float(bool restart, ActiveConfig<Traits> config,
                    float sample) 
{
   // save to 'state'
   %\tikzmark{statb}%static Impl state;%\tikzmark{state}%
   $\ldots$
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape,escapechar=\%]
float flicker_float_r(bool restart, ActiveConfig<Traits> config,
                      float sample, %\tikzmark{parb}%Impl *state%\tikzmark{pare}%) 
{
   // save to *state
   $\ldots$
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=-2pt}]
  \fill[opacity=.1] (pic cs:statb) rectangle ($(pic cs:state) + (0,10pt)$ -| {pic cs:state});
  \fill[opacity=0.1] (pic cs:parb) rectangle ([yshift=10pt]pic cs:pare);
% \fill[opacity=0.1] (pic cs:parb) rectangle ($(pic cs:pare) + (0,10pt)$);

% uncomment to see straight line  
%  \draw (pic cs:parb) -- ($(pic cs:parb) + (0,10pt)$ -| {pic cs:pare});

  \draw[->] (pic cs:statb) -| ([xshift=-5pt]pic cs:parb) -- +(5pt,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```